# Active Alternatives to Blather for XMPP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xmpp, xmpp4r

While maintaining a project which uses the XMPP4R gem, I began looking at the documentation and noticed that the GitHub for https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r is no longer active, and has not been for at least two years.

After visiting the XMPP site for libraries available for Ruby http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/ there are only 5 options listed for Ruby:

- Babylon - https://github.com/bryanwoods/babylon - GitHub inactive for 4 years
- Blather - https://github.com/adhearsion/blather - Recently updated
- Loudmouth - https://github.com/mhallendal/loudmouth - GitHub inactive for 5 years
- XMPP4r - https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r - GitHub inactive for 2 years
- xmpp4r-simple - https://github.com/blaine/xmpp4r-simple - GitHub inactive for 4 years

So with the exception of Blather, all of the listed Ruby XMPP libraries seem to no longer be supported. While I am not absolutely against using Blather, before I make a decision to migrate from XMPP4R I wanted to ask the question.

OLD: What are the alternatives to Blather as an XMPP library for Ruby that are actively maintained?

EDIT: Going to try re-phrase the question to better suit the SO format, so it doesn't seem like a shopping question!

I understand that XMPP is an older spec, and it does not appear that Blather is the de facto standard for XMPP for Ruby, or that there even is one. So *why are there so few actively developed XMPP libraries for Ruby?* Surely the older libraries were not perfect!

(Though this is somewhat of a subjective question, but I feel this still fits the format SO has laid out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blather is by far the best option anyway (I created Babylon back in the day!). XMPP4R is not reommanded as it uses threads and is notoriously hard to scale. The only drawback of #blather is that it uses EventMachine which itself seems to be slowly dying.